# Javascript file for only some views in Rails 3.1

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In Rails 3.1, what is a neat way to include a javascript file for only some views and exclude it from others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the view you want the script,

```
<%- content_for :javascript do -%> 
  <script type="text/javascript"> ... </script>
<%- end -%>
```

An alternative to the above, I use a javascript_include_tag pointing to the js file for that script instead of using the  tag so that I can keep all my javascript in one place.

```
<%- content_for :javascript do -%> 
  <%= javascript_include_tag "example.js" %>
<%- end -%>
```

In the layout for that view where you have your other javascript:

```
   <%= yield :javascript %>
```

Comment: When I do that, it works locally on my machine, but it does not work on Heroku; Heroku log says 2011-11-11T08:40:13+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/supersized/supersized.3.1-a1b831482ae0b46b8f13ee52bb57bab0.3"):

Comment: That looks to be an issue with rails 3.1 javascript fingerprints/caching.  If you are not using caching in your config set config.assets.digest false for production.  If you are using fingerprints, checkout the assest pipline documentation for more options. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: Did you try removing the .js from `example.js`

Answer (score 1):

In your particular html.erb file add these lines

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "name_of_js_file" %>
```